# countable and uncountable subset of $P(\omega)$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Consider the following statement (P):

> For every subset $\emptyset \not = A \subset P(\omega)$, there exists a subset $B\subset A$ such that $B \subset A$ such that :
>
> 1) $B$ is countable (i.e. is either finite or has cardinal $\aleph_0$)
>
> 2) $\bigcap B = \bigcap A$
>
> 3) $\bigcup B = \bigcup A$

Is (P) true? Asaf Karagila have given me [an answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713031/countable-and-uncountable-subset-of-p-omega/2713111#2713111), namely that (P) is true under the Axiom of Choice (AC).

My question is : is (P) true regardless of AC ?!

If not could you please post the best way to use AC in this question ?

Comment: I don't see a question....

Comment: What’s the question? And there’s a typo in (3)?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg thanks ,corrected the post

Comment: @JeremyRickard thanks , corrected the post, could you please have a look at it

Comment: What's $B$? a subset? a Boolean subalgebra? ...

Comment: I don't understand why there are complaints about the question, since it seems perfectly clear. He has a family of subsets of $\omega$ and he wants a countable subfamily with the same intersection and union. This is easy using the axiom of choice, and (my answer shows) impossible  to prove without any form of choice.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I agree that the question is now clear, but most of the complaints (mine, at least) are from before the question was edited to address our comments.

Comment: OK, that's fine. I guess the comments were about a version of the question that does not show up in the edit history, since even the first version there seems perfectly clear. What confused me is that the comments are after the five minute period.

Comment: @Joel: There are complaints because I explicitly wrote in my answer that AC is necessary. Apparently, that was a good enough reason to ask it again here, and receive what is essentially the same answer. And if the OP had asked me to elaborate, I would have gladly done so in my answer on MSE.

Comment: (And of course there should have been a link provided to the MSE question.)

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, since I find it to be fine for MO, and interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is relatively consistent with ZF that this is impossible.

Suppose that there is an infinite Dedekind finite set $A\subset P(\omega)$. Since ZF proves that the continuum is bijective with the set of branches through the binary tree $2^{<\omega}$, we may assume by labeling the nodes of this tree that 
no finite subset of $A$ has the same union as $A$. But since $A$ is Dedekind finite, it has no countably infinite subsets. So in this case, there is no countable $B\subset A$ with the same union as $A$. So it is a counterexample to your requested property.

So you cannot prove the existence of $B$ in ZF.

Comment: so one needs the Axiom of Choice, could you please give me a hint on how to apply AC to solve this question ?

Comment: Didn't you say Asaf explained that? It's easy: for each $n\in \cup A$, pick a set $x_n\in A$ with $n\in x_n$, and let $B=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Oops, to get also condition (2), you have also to include $y_n\in A$ where $n\notin y_n$, if there is any such $y\in A$.

Comment: i may be getting this totally wrong but i think AC works on countable sets so it can't choose a set from uncountable set $A$ ?

Comment: AC for countable families is a strictly weaker principle. In general, the axiom of choice applies to any set of nonempty sets.

Comment: A tangential observation: If you use the most familiar example of a Dedekind-finite subset $A$ of $P(\omega)$, the set of Cohen reals explicitly added in building the basic Cohen model, then you don't need the part of the argument about about the tree $2^{<\omega}$, because, by genericity, $\bigcup A=\omega$ and $\bigcap A=\varnothing$, and no finite subset of $A$ has (either of) these properties.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, that is nice.  Meanwhile, my argument shows that every model with an infinite Dedekind-finite set of reals will have a counterexample to the property.

Comment: Joel, I am thoroughly confused as to why you bring up the binary tree in this context, one can easily show that by removing finitely many elements you have to have a set without maximum or minimum (otherwise, by their uniqueness, you have a countable set). Of course, this is not "without loss of generality", but rather "if there is a DF set $A$, then there is a counterexample".

Comment: Suppose for every set in the family, I also add the complement. Now I have an infinite DF set for which you cannot just "remove finitely many elements" to make an example without a finite solution to the OP. As far as I can see, you really need something like the tree argument.

Comment: Uh, unless you also included $\omega$ and $\varnothing$, adding complements is an even simpler solution, as it ensures the union is everything (which is not in the set) and the intersection is empty (which is not in the set either). And if you did include these, then remove them. (And if you ping me, I will be able to respond faster without having to guess that you replied to my comment, by the way. :))

Comment: I thought you are pinged automaticaly without specifically mentioning @AsafKaragila. If the union is $\omega$ and the intersection if $\emptyset$, then the point is that perhaps one can do it with even a finite set (as in my example where we added all the complements), so this won't make a counterexample. That is, if $A$ is an infinite Dedekind-finite subset of $P(\omega)$, then if $A$ is closed under complements, then the OP's property is trivial, since any pair of a set and its complement fulfills it.

Comment: It only pings automatically if you are the author of the post (in this case, you) or if there is exactly one other person who have commented (so Ahmad got pinged in your initial back and forth, after Andreas has commented, you'd have to specify the user.

Comment: I see what you mean about a finite set. Okay, I concede to your point (although I still think that your use of "WLOG" is not justified here...) :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila What argument do you have in mind without my tree argument? You need to show that if there is in an infinite DF set A, then there is such a set A for which no finite set has the right union and intersection. I proved this by going to the tree $2^{<\omega}$. But how do you do this otherwise? You need to spread out your DF set somehow.

Comment: Joel, I figured that if there is one, then there is one in a $\Bbb R$-chain in $\mathcal P(\omega)$, and as a linearly ordered set my arguments for removing finitely many works even better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't understand that, but I do understand my argument with the tree $2^{{<}\omega}$, which is very easy. So I guess I prefer my argument.

Comment: Well, if $\mathcal P(\omega)$ has a Dedekind-finite subset, then any set of that cardinality has one too. In particular any chain in $\mathcal P(\omega)$ which is order-isomorphic to the real numbers with their standard linear order. So without loss of generality, we can assume that our DF set is in fact a $\subseteq$-chain.

Comment: OK, but that is essentially the same as what my tree argument accomplishes. I was simply reducing to the case where no finite subset would work.

Comment: And merely having a chain isn't enough, as you noted, since you still need possibly to remove finitely many points at the top and bottom; so my tree argument is better, isn't it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, forgot to ping you.